# ListView crashing in fragment - onClick Method

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

For some reason, I am having trouble with my application crashing when I try to make this listView in a fragment. I have seen several things about needing to use something instead of view because the view has not been created yet. Is there a way to restructure this code or something to change so it works? Here is the code. Sorry I am brand new to Android. **The code is crashing when I try to click the send button, so I am assuming somewhere in the onClick method.**

```
package com.quickCollab.project;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.quickCollab.project.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Chat extends Fragment {

private String message;
private EditText messageField;
private ListView mainListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> chatList = new ArrayList<String>();
private View chat;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    chat = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_frag, container, false);
    chatList.add("Welcome");
    Button send = (Button) chat.findViewById(R.id.send);
    messageField = (EditText) chat.findViewById(R.id.username);
    mainListView = (ListView) chat.findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.simplerow, chatList);

    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Got this far");
            message = messageField.getText().toString();
            chatList.add(message);


            send();
            System.out.println(chatList.toString());
            /*
            if (message.length() > 0) {
                listAdapter.add(message);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                message = "";
                listAdapter.add(message);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }*/

        };

    });

    return chat;
}

public void send() {        
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

there has been a request for the logcat error. thanks for all your help!

```
12-08 22:45:11.456: I/Adreno-EGL(29631): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
12-08 22:45:11.456: I/Adreno-EGL(29631): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
12-08 22:45:11.456: I/Adreno-EGL(29631): Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
12-08 22:45:11.456: I/Adreno-EGL(29631): Local Branch: 0328_AU200_patches
12-08 22:45:11.456: I/Adreno-EGL(29631): Remote Branch: 
12-08 22:45:11.456: I/Adreno-EGL(29631): Local Patches: 
12-08 22:45:11.456: I/Adreno-EGL(29631): Reconstruct Branch: 
12-08 22:45:11.486: D/OpenGLRenderer(29631): Enabling debug mode 0
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): DFactory start
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): This is decoding
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): onDecode : stream read 54 bytes, ptr = 0x72d8bef0
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): onDecode : QmageDecParseHeader call : QM
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): Qmage parsing for decoding ok
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): onDecode : QmageHeader Height() 96 Width() : 96 sampleSize : 1
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): Qmage Make Color table[2]
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): Qmage Mae Color table end
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): 1 to 1 Index mode decoding
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): 1 to 1 Index mode decoding end
12-08 22:45:11.506: D/(29631): onDecode : return true
12-08 22:45:12.016: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29631): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Your chatList has no value.. you directly used the chatlist to set your adapter .. Obviously you are getting a null pointer. Initialize your chatlist and add values to it first and then set in the adapter.

Comment: can u show ur `imports`

Comment: I have fixed that, but the onClick method seems to be the culprit now. Any idea what the issue is, note the code has been updated!

Comment: You have just notify your adapter but after add new data in chatlist you didn't set adapter for listview. so you are getting error.

Comment: LogCat and imports have been posted. Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: @GaryMcSperry log shows nothing one suggestion pass `TextView's` id of `simplerow` layout while creating `Adapter` and in send button's click event check `message` is *null* or not if not *null* then do all the operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private ArrayList<String> chatList;`

You used `chatList` to populate your listview, but you did not initialize that `chatList` with any value.

`listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.simplerow, chatList);`

So while creating `listAdapter` it will return `NullPointerException`, please instantiate your `chatList` and iterate with any value, try again.

Comment: That fixed part of it! Any idea why the onClick method is crashing?

Comment: please post your Logcat